# How to execute a sql-server function from PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, function

I have function in MSSQL and I need to start that from PHP. My connection is ready, but I don't know howto execute from PHP.

Here's the function I try to execute:

```
USE [database]
GO
DECLARE     @return_value int
EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[ict_es2_import_ceniku]
@Id_ceniku = N'Maloobchodni cenik'
SELECT      'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!

```
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = 'xxx';
$dbname = "xxx";


$dbcon = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die("Unable to connect to MSSQL");
mssql_select_db($dbname, $dbcon); // vybere databázi

$stmt = mssql_init('ict_es2_import_ceniku');
$variace = 'Maloobchodni cenik';
$Id_ceniku = '@Id_ceniku';
mssql_bind($stmt, $Id_ceniku, $variace,  SQLTEXT, false);
mssql_execute($stmt);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
echo $return_value;
```

Comment: Its good you find the solution, Just for my understanding how will you get the $return_value. (Is it $return_value=mssql_execute($stmt);)

Answer (score 1):

mssql_execute — Executes a stored procedure on a MS SQL server database

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-init.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php

```
// Create a new statement
$stmt = mssql_init('ict_es2_import_ceniku');

// Bind values
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Id_ceniku',    'Maloobchodni cenik',  SQLTEXT, false);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@return_value',    $return_value,  SQLINT, true);

// Execute the statement
mssql_execute($stmt);

// And we can free it like so:
mssql_free_statement($stmt);

echo $return_value;
```

Comment: Yes it will definitely correct way to call stored procedure. +1 from me

Comment: I find it too, but I can not use it.

Comment: Hari Swaminathan: $stmt = mssql_init('@return_value');
// Execute the statement
mssql_execute($stmt);

// And we can free it like so:
mssql_free_statement($stmt);¨

Comment: @Bojkas $stmt = mssql_init('<you stored procedure name>'); you need to give the sp name as parameter to mssql_init method

Comment: I dont realy know. :-/ Procedure name is "ict_es2_import_ceniku" and parametr "Maloobchodni cenik"

Only one thing, where can i write parameter?

Comment: From the code you pasted its clear that the sp name and input parameters

Comment: one thing, where can i write parameter?

Comment: I try this form first post and Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /www/doc/www.seznambot.cz/www/procedura.php on line 27

Comment: <?php

$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$hostname = 'xxxx';
$dbname = "xxxx";


$dbcon = mssql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die("Unable to connect to MSSQL"); // připojení k DB mssql
mssql_select_db($dbname, $dbcon); // vybere databázi



// Create a new statement
$stmt = mssql_init('ict_es2_import_ceniku');

// Bind values
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Id_ceniku', 'Maloobchodni cenik',  SQLTEXT, false);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@return_value', $return_value,  SQLINT, true);

// Execute the statement
mssql_execute($stmt);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
echo $return_value;
?>

Comment: error is here: mssql_bind($stmt, '@Id_ceniku', 'Maloobchodni cenik',  SQLTEXT, false);

Comment: A tryed this but still somewhere problem. Now in second mssql_bind.
mssql_bind() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in


$stmt = mssql_init('ict_es2_import_ceniku');

// Bind values
$variace = 'Maloobchodni cenik';
$Id_ceniku = '@Id_ceniku';
mssql_bind($stmt, $Id_ceniku, $variace,  SQLTEXT, false);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@return_value',    $return_value,  SQLINT, true);

// Execute the statement
mssql_execute($stmt);

// And we can free it like so:
mssql_free_statement($stmt);

echo $return_value;

Comment: @Bojkas Plz  go through the three reference sites quoted in answer and restructure your code.

Comment: @Bojkas I don't have a MSSQL server installed in PC to test this, plz try at your end. Meanwhile I will try to setup MSSQL, run this code and update you.